# JavaScript: Open PDF file inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, uri

I'm trying to open a PDF file inside an iframe but so far it doesn't work. I have something like this:

```
this.load("data:application/pdf;base64,"+btoa((response),"file.pdf");

load: function(uri, name){

    var iframe = Ext.get('myIframe');  

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    link.target = iframe;
    link.click();
}
```

I need that the PDF file be open inside this iframe but I don´t know the way to reach this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ext JS?

Instead of 
link.target = iframe;

Try 
link.target = 'myIframe'; //name of iframe

Comment: Yes Vijay, I´m using Ext Js, I tried but It doesn´t work :C